# What do you call a newbie individual investor in the stock market?

Tags: slang

Is there some slang word for a newbie individual investor in the stock market? For example, in Russia, we call them "hamsters", that is, these are people who have just entered the stock market and are poorly versed in it, they usually lose money due to inexperience.

Comment: The term *piker* ( https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/piker.asp) is similar, but not not an exact fit in that it is not so much about newness as about caution and making small, risk adverse trades.

Answer (score 1):

***[Novice investor](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/novice-investor)***:

> So how would he suggest a novice investor, without his technical knowledge, start investing?
> (Times, Sunday Times)

> An awful lot of novice investors have been burnt already.
> (Times, Sunday Times)

(Collins)